# How to reemplace new line( \n ) for comma and space (', ') XPATH 1.0

Tags: xpath, xpath-1.0

I have the next string:

```
AAAAAAA
BBBBBBB BBBBBBB
CCCCCCC CCCCCCC
```

I would like to have the next string:

```
AAAAAAA, BBBBBBB BBBBBBB, CCCCCCC CCCCCCC
```

Thank you if you could help my I only could do it with XPATH 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

In XPath 1.0 we have to rely on `translate()` along with `normalize-space()` instead of the handy `replace()`:

```
translate(normalize-space(/),' ',',')
```

[Online Demo](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?&data=AAAAAAA%0ABBBBBBB%20BBBBBBB%0ACCCCCCC%20CCCCCCC&=&extract=translate(normalize-space(%2F)%2C%27%20%27%2C%27%2C%27)%0A&=translate(normalize-space(%2F)%2C%27%20%27%2C%27%2C%27)%0A&input-format=xml&printed-node-format=html&output-format=adhoc&compatibility=Enable%20all%20extensions&dot-notation=unambiguous&extract-kind=xpath2)

The downside of this approach is we can only translate to a single character, so no extra space after the comma. But for all intents and purposes, this should be cosmetic only.

Comment: The problem is the space. that we have between the new lines and also to weep the space without comma